# Hook to add new field to node form

Tags: hooks, forms

I have a blog content type which has a field for authors- (these are pull from a separate content type). multiple values are allowed.
i am trying to develop a module that will pull the authors email address and display it next to the authors name when ever a new author is added in the blog create form so users can edit the email on the fly while creating a new blog post.

i need some pointer as to the right hooks to use for these.
Thanks in advance.
See screenshot below of what am trying to archive 
[image: enter image description hered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it myself -- but see [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) which should allow you to reference an existing author, or implement that modules form controller class to show an author and email field to create the new author as needed.

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification,
>   removal) of referenced entities. The primary use case is the parent ->
>   children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.),
>   where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>   Existing entities can also be referenced.

From the [README](http://drupalcode.org/project/inline_entity_form.git/blob/a0f8bf8c59b5aa35d03383ec6a0b77791a8c149f:/README)

```
Integrating with Inline Entity Form
-----------------------------------
An entity type can add support for this module by declaring the
inline entity form controller class in its entity info:

$entity_info['commerce_line_item']['inline entity form'] = array(
  'controller' => 'CommerceLineItemInlineEntityFormController',
);

The controller needs to extend EntityInlineEntityFormController and at least
override entityForm() to provide a function entity form.
```

Comment: Thanks his didnt achieve that out of box but with some customization using a custom module i was able to add this functionality using this module